# Finite generation of algebraic $K$-theory with finite coefficients

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, algebraic-k-theory

Given a smooth connected complex quasi-projective variety $X$, is it possible that $K_i(X, \mathbb{Z}/l)$ to be infinitely generated for $i>0$? I think Quillen-Lichtenbaum implies that above the dimension  $K_i(X, \mathbb{Z}/l)$ coincides with the topological $K$-theory which will be finitely generated.

Comment: Variety over what? Do you suppose something like $\ell$ being invertible on $X$?

Comment: @Z.M Complex variety i.e. over complex numbers. Yes naturally $\ell$ is invertible in char zero for all choices.